# How do an OR condition in a EL expression?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

I would like to make an OR condition in this menu :

```
<li class="#{facesContext.viewRoot.viewId == ('/company/team.xhtml' or '/company/partnerships.xhtml' ) ? 'active' : '' }"><a class="item" href="company/company.xhtml">Company</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="company/team.xhtml">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="company/partnerships.xhtml">Partnerships</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

That if the `team.xthml` or `partnerships.xhtml` page are selected by the user the 'active' value would be set it in the `<li>` tag.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is the proper syntax:

```
<li class="#{facesContext.viewRoot.viewId == '/company/team.xhtml' or facesContext.viewRoot.viewId == '/company/partnerships.xhtml' ? 'active' : '' }">
```

To make it a bit shorter, you could use `#{view}` instead of `#{facesContext.viewRoot}`:

```
<li class="#{view.viewId == '/company/team.xhtml' or view.viewId == '/company/partnerships.xhtml' ? 'active' : '' }">
```

To make it yet shorter, you could alias the `#{view.viewId}` with [`<c:set>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/c/set.html):

```
<c:set var="viewId" value="#{view.viewId}" scope="request" />
...
<li class="#{viewId == '/company/team.xhtml' or viewId == '/company/partnerships.xhtml' ? 'active' : '' }">
```